# Was there ever a resolution to the conflict in the Battletech cartoon?

Tags: cartoon, battletech

I'm aware that the 1990s *Battletech* cartoon is only loosely based on the video game franchise of the same name. As such, the stories will diverge. This question relates specifically to the cartoon though...

Was there any canonical resolution to the conflict or solid ending for this team?

Comment: Battletech is the tabletop game franchise. Mechwarrior is the video game adaptation of Battletech.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no. There was no second season. And while FASA acknowledged the characters and events in subsequent novels and a sourcebook, there's no resolution for the people of Somerset. The events of the cartoon are described as a "poorly reviewed (but otherwise popular) Anti-Clan propaganda holo-vid" that were loosely based on real events, and the people involved apparently went their separate ways with Adam Steiner and Franklin Sakamoto returning to their home nations.

From the House Steiner entry in *Masters and Minions - The Starcorp Dossiers*:

> Ushered into the realities of war during the
> Clan Invasion in 3050, he was thrown into a leadership role from
> his former position as an academy instructor. He was so successful and such an atypical Lyran officer that his exploits leading the
> Somerset Strikers spawned a popular tri-vid show aimed at young
> Lyrans, instilling national pride into the newer generation – along-
> side selling trillions of L-bills in toys and merchandise. [*In proper
> Lyran merchant tradition, of course. –ED*]
>
> Even though the Strikers were disbanded shortly after the
> invasion halted on Tukayyid, Adam continued to rise up the
> LAAF ladder, becoming Archon Peter Steiner-Davion’s General
> of the armies after the FedCom Civil War. His promotion was
> quickly tested when the Blakists unleashed their Jihad, hammering several key Lyran worlds and setting the nation back
> on its heels.

From *Era Report: 3052*:

> But in early 3052, Adam Steiner managed to prevail upon the AFFC to let him lead another foray into Clan territories, this time targeting the rear-echelon world of Barcelona. Here, facing second-line forces, and in command of a substantially larger formation based around his Somerset Strikers, is where the man who would one day be Archon truly earned his command stripes.
>
> Sadly, many of the more heroic details of this battle were seeded throughout the holo series that celebrated Adam Steiner’s exploits. This produced a myth for the viewing audiences that had less to do with reality than AFFC recruiting offices cared to admit at the time.

While it's not exactly a resolution, the *1st Somerset Strikers* sourcebook does include a partial explanation for the missing people (note that the source book says that parts of the book were written from the original scripts and storyboards, and may not match the broadcast episodes).

[image: Explanation of where the people went] <sub>click to enlarge</sub>

> INTELLIGENCE SECRETARIAT INTERNAL MEMO NO. 7688-----G
>
> **TO: Marshal Daniel Darwith/MI2/Tharkad
>
> FROM: Hauptamn Neil Stanger
>
> ROUTING: MOST URGENT
>
> RE: Depopulation of Somerset**
>
> **CLASSIFICATION: EYES ONLY**
>
> We have received the initial report on Major Steiner's actions on Somerset, along with supplemental materials (see enclosures). An analysis of these materials lead to a terrifying conclusion.
>
> Somerset has been totally depopulated. Not a single civilian of the Feder5ated Commonwealth remains. According to Major Steiner's report, this event occurred in less than an hour.
>
> As pf the 3045 census, the population of Somerset numbered roughly one million people. The number and types of Clan DropShips that lifted off from Somerset were well documented by sensors from the DCJS *Katana*. At maximum loads, these ships could have only carried a total of 10,000 people. Analysis of their engine thrusts indicate that these ships were carrying only 84.6% of their maximum load. These ships left the planet within 50 minutes of the evacuation orders.
>
> It is obvious that the Jade Falcons could not have, and in fact did not, evacuate the planetary population immediately after the "Trial of Possession" won by Major Steiner. Therefore, the population of Somerset must have been forced offplanet prior to the arrival of the Strikers!
>
> The transcript of the interrogation of a Falcon technician gives us a vital clue as to what really happened. The technician, known as Olga, stated that "... most have been indoctrinated into the Way of the Clans, absorbed into either the technician or labor castes."
>
> The implications are clear. The Clans are indoctrinating Federated Commonwealth civilians and then forcibly transporting them from their homes to serve the Jade Falcons in whatever capacity the Clans deem appropriate. The Clans call these new citizens "bondsmen," but we in the Inner Sphere have another name for them ... slaves.

I also found mention of a proposed direction for the second season [here](https://www.sarna.net/wiki/BattleTech:_The_Animated_Series#Notes) (bolding mine):

> Sam Lewis, when asked about the cartoon show in a 2022 interview, mentioned that Episode 5A was special because of a problem during production (not on FASA's side, he stressed); as a result, this episode made use of cel animation footage that had originally been meant to be used instead of the computer generated "Enhanced Imaging" battle footage as a fallback measure because the producers had doubted whether FASA could actually produce the computer animation on time. **He also said that there were no written storylines for a second season, but the general idea would have been for Adam Steiner go to into Clan space to rescue his people**.